# Move rows not null to start from first column in Pandas

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

In Pandas, I would like to shift rows in my dataframe to eliminate every cell with a value less than 1, in order to start each row with non null values in the first column. For example, the original data:

```
Name    first_column    second_column   third_column    ...
first   0   0   1   ...
second  1   3   5   ...
third   0   3   8   ...
fourth  0   0   5   ...
```

The desired output:

```
Name    first_column    second_column   third_column
first   1   ... ...
second  1   3   5
third   3   8   ...
fourth  5   ... ...
```

Any idea which formula to use in Pandas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df=df.mask(df.eq(0)).T.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull)).T
     Name first_column second_column third_column
0   first            1           NaN          NaN
1  second            1             3            5
2   third            3             8          NaN
3  fourth            5           NaN          NaN
```